# Trouble using the Xonar Essence STX soundcard

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa, soundcard

I'm trying to get my Asus Xonar STX soundcard to work.

It is recognized in the kernal if i type:

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: STX [Xonar STX], device 0: Multichannel [Multichannel]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: STX [Xonar STX], device 1: Digital [Digital]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I have already tried to disable the onboard sound device, This just means that i have no sound at all.

Another note, I can see the device listed on the alsamixer. It does seem to control the hardware to some extent. It will click the soundcard when i change the Analogue out. (in alsamixer as well as the System Settings -> Sound gui)

I not sure what the next step should be. Perhaps blacklisting the Video card sound device. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually took the sledgehammer approach, and reinstalled alsa, and parts of the ubuntu desktop.

[Found here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)

Code:

```
cat /proc/asound/{version,cards,devices,hwdep,pcm,seq/clients}; sudo rm
/etc/asound.conf; sudo rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ;sudo rm ~/.pulse-cookie; sudo 
apt-get update; sudo apt-get install aptitude; sudo aptitude install paman gnome-
alsamixer libasound2-plugins padevchooser libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio; sudo lshw 
-short;ls -lart /dev/snd;  cat /dev/sndstat; lspci -nn; lsusb; sudo which alsactl; 
sudo fuser -v /dev/dsp /dev/snd/* ; dpkg -S bin/slmodemd; dmesg | egrep 
'EMU|probe|emu|ALSA|alsa|ac97|udi|snd|ound|irmware'; sudo /etc/init.d/sl-modem-
daemon status; sudo grep model /etc/modprobe.d/* ; sudo dmidecode|egrep 
'anufact|roduct|erial|elease'; lsmod | egrep 'snd|usb|midi|udio'; pacmd list-sinks; 
aplay -l; sudo alsa force-reload;  ubuntu-support-status ; sudo lshw -C sound
```

Sound is now working after reboot.

Keep in mind that there more precise methods found in the above troubleshooter. This is not the best first option.

Answer (score 1):

To make the Xonar the first sound card, edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base`(.conf) and add this line:

```
options snd slots=snd-virtuoso,snd-hda-intel,snd-hda-intel
```

(You do not need to disable the on-board device.)

In theory, you could just select the Xonar in the sound configuration, but this would affect only programs that use PulseAudio.

Comment: Thanks. It did in fact put the STX to the top. This turned out to not be the issue. Thanks though.